# hibernate cast base class into subclass

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

Ok I got a base class and a subclass

what I want to do is to turn base class into sub class in sql table

By changing discriminator value inside xml at run time without using annotation

how can I achieve such an approach
I'm using shared table per subclasses

Comment: Take a look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

We can do the Hibernate Inhertitance with and without using annotation

Take a look at this article

1.**[Table Per Hierarchy using xml file](http://www.javatpoint.com/hibernate-table-per-hierarchy-example-using-xml-file)**
 2.**[Table Per Concrete class using xml file](http://www.javatpoint.com/table-per-concrete-class)**
 3.**[Table Per Subclass using xml file](http://www.javatpoint.com/table-per-subclass)**

Comment: ok sir i understand all that i just want to change value of discriminator at run time to save base class as a subclass inside database